# ASP.NET redirecting certain pages to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm very new to ASP.NET and I'm trying to create a simple CRUD application, I want to have certain pages redirect to the login page if a user is not logged in.  I don't want to do a site wide redirect to login for all pages that are not the home page.  I have been messing around with the controllers and have found that using this code in the controllers will redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return View(db.Events.ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Account/Login",true);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that this is definitely not in best practices of ASP.NET.  If somebody could explain why or point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `[Authorize]` attribute and it will redirect to the login page if the user is not authorized.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

which is your login page you need to configure in the web.config

Comment: If this answer has solved your problem, please choose it as the selected answer @ChrisRiv91

Comment: @AydinAdn Just did, was locked out from doing it for a few minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

You an use an [Authorize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute on an entire controller or specific controller methods.  If the user does not yet have roles because they did not log in, they will be redirected to the login page

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SomeAppRole")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

or

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SomeAppRole")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  // etc
}
```

Note that the roles are optional.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The roles might come in handy later down the road.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Authorize attribute in you action.

```
[Authorize] 
public class HomeController: Controller{

  [Authorize]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {}


  [Authorize]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {}

  [AllowAnonymous]
  public ActionResult Help()
  {}
}
```

you can apply the Authoirze attribute in controller level so that you don't have to apply it to all the action in the controller.

If you want to ignore any action from using Authorize that is applied in controller level then you can mark the action with  [AllowAnonymous] attribute

Comment: Good to know about the [AllowAnonymous], that will definitely help!